# I've got code to randomize an image on refresh in javascript and CSS to format the image but I don't know how to combine the two

Tags: javascript, css

I'm sorry if the title doesn't make sense, I'm extremely new to this, so here's a jsfiddle of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/a3668a1f/1/

I want the images that show up below the title box to appear in the title box.

I just threw those images in there as an example.

```js
var images = [
  "https://i.redd.it/1ev9elr85xcz.jpg",
  "https://i.redd.it/g6kc3upsvqdz.jpg",
  "https://i.redd.it/koucki3aygdz.jpg"
];

function randImg() {
  var size = images.length
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
  document.getElementById('image').src = images[x];
}

randImg();
```

```css
h1 {
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 85px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/pvqzvajftpdz.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Title.
    <img id="image" />
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked the `<>` snippet editor for you and created a [mcve] here

Comment: What is the problem other than the image size? If I add `img { height: 50px }` they are all inside the box

Comment: I want one of the images that are in the javascript to be the background image of the inside of that box on refresh, instead of the image of the dog.

Comment: yep that worked! thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
var images = [
  "https://i.redd.it/1ev9elr85xcz.jpg",
  "https://i.redd.it/g6kc3upsvqdz.jpg",
  "https://i.redd.it/koucki3aygdz.jpg"
];

function randImg() {
  var size = images.length
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
  document.querySelector('h1').style.backgroundImage='url('+images[x]+')';
}

randImg();
```

```css
h1 {
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 85px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-width: 5px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/pvqzvajftpdz.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Title.
    <img id="image" />
  </h1>
</div>
```